# Problem with adding element's whitespace between submitted text

Tags: html, css

I'm facing an issue where if I submit data to the right card, it won't add whitespace or padding in-between the next submitted data.

Here's the desired layout:
[image: Concept]

I've attempted to add margins and paddings, but with no success.

```
.card:nth-child(2) ul {
  align-items: center;
  grid-area: c2;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #664caf;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.card:nth-child(2) ul li {
  align-items: center;
  grid-area: c2;
  list-style: numeric;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

So my guess was that there is an issue with `.card:nth-child(2)`

Here is a Codepen link: https://codepen.io/arkzy/pen/rNoPqyX

Please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `border-radius` and `background-color` items to the list item and added `padding` and `margin` options.

Padding adds space on the inside of the element, whereas margin adds space to the outside of it.

Here's my snippet:

```css
#notes {
  align-items: center;
  grid-area: c2;
}

#notes li {
  align-items: center;
  grid-area: c2;
  list-style: numeric;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #664caf;
  margin: 10pt;
  padding: 10pt;
}
```

This has the following result:
[spaced list items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBnb5.png)

Presuming this is what you wanted of course.

I also suggest using the id tags `#notes` because `nth-child(n)` will break if you add more cards to your html.